# When do I need to use a GeoSeries when creating a GeoDataFrame, and when is a list enough?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, geopandas, shapely

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, Point
import numpy as np
```

---

I define a polygon:

```
polygon = Polygon([(0,0),(0,1),(1,1),(1,0)])
```

and create a list of random points:

```
np.random.seed(42)
points = [Point([np.random.uniform(low=-1,high=1),
                 np.random.uniform(low=-1,high=1)]) for _ in range(1000)]
```

I want to know which points are within the polygon. I create a `GeoDataFrame` with a column called `points`, by first converting the `points` `list` to `GeoSeries`:

```
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(dict(points=gpd.GeoSeries(points)))
```

Then simply do:

```
gdf.points.within(polygon)
```

which returns a `pandas.core.series.Series` of booleans, indicating which points are within the polygon.

However, if I don't create the GeoDataFrame from a `list`, not a `GeoSeries` object:

```
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(dict(points=points))
```

and then do:

```
gdf.points.within(polygon)
```

I get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-171-831eddc859a1> in <module>()
----> 1 gdf.points.within(polygon)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5485         ):
   5486             return self[name]
-> 5487         return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5488 
   5489     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'within'
```

In the examples given on the [geopandas.GeoDataFrame](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.html) page, a `GeoDataFrame` is create from a `list`, not a `GeoSeries` of `shapely.geometry.Point` objects:

```
from shapely.geometry import Point
d = {'col1': ['name1', 'name2'], 'geometry': [Point(1, 2), Point(2, 1)]}
gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(d, crs="EPSG:4326")
```

---

**When do I need to convert my `list`s to `GeoSeries` first, and when can I keep them as `list`s when creating `GeoDataFrame`s?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On [the docs for `geopandas.GeoDataFrame`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.html#geopandas.GeoDataFrame), where you got your example, there's a little note:

> Notice that the inferred dtype of ‘geometry’ columns is geometry.

Which can be seen [here](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/blob/212cb9c2b5112fdee4ce403bf0a51a395d528628/geopandas/geodataframe.py#L23), and you can observe it yourself:

```
>>> import geopandas as gpd

>>> gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': [Point(0,0)]}).dtypes
geometry    geometry
dtype: object

>>> gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometryXXX': [Point(0,0)]}).dtypes
geometryXXX    object
dtype: object
```

From [the docs for `geopandas.GeoSeries`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.html#geopandas.GeoSeries):

> A Series object designed to store shapely geometry objects.

...so it makes sense that it would try to convert the objects it's created with to the `geometry` dtype. In fact, when you try to create a GeoSeries with non-shapely objects, you'll get a warning:

```
>>> gpd.GeoSeries([1,2,3])
<ipython-input-53-ca5248fcdaf8>:1: FutureWarning:     You are passing non-geometry data to the GeoSeries constructor. Currently,
    it falls back to returning a pandas Series. But in the future, we will start
    to raise a TypeError instead.
  gpd.GeoSeries([1,2,3])
```

...which, as the warning says, will become an error in the future.

---

Since you're *not* creating a GeoSeries object (your using a list instead), and since the column *is not* called `geometry`, the `GeoDataFrame` makes its dtype be the most general it can convert the objects within to - `object`. Therefore, since the column is of dtype `object` and not `geometry`, you can't call `geometry`-specific methods, such as `within`.

If you need to use a list, you've two simple choices.

**Method 1. Pass the `geometry=` keyword argument to `GeoDataFrame()`:**

```
>>> gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'points': [Point(0,0), Point(0,1)]}, geometry='points')
>>> gdf['points'].dtypes
<geopandas.array.GeometryDtype at 0x12882a1c0>
>>> gdf['points'].within
<bound method GeoPandasBase.within of 0    POINT (0.00000 0.00000)
1    POINT (0.00000 1.00000)
Name: points, dtype: geometry>
```

**Method 2. Use `astype` like you'd do with a normal dataframe:**

```
>>> gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'points': [Point(0,0), Point(0,1)]})
>>> gdf['points'].dtype
dtype('O')
>>> gdf['points'].within
...
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'within'

>>> gdf['points'] = gdf['points'].astype('geometry')
>>> gdf['points'].dtype
<geopandas.array.GeometryDtype at 0x122189e20>
>>> gdf['points'].within
<bound method GeoPandasBase.within of 0    POINT (0.00000 0.00000)
1    POINT (0.00000 1.00000)
Name: points, dtype: geometry>
```